# Parsing an XML with 2 default namespace in Java using DOM parser

Tags: java, xml, dom

Thanks in advance.

I have a xml with 2 default namespace at rootlevel and then as element level.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Msg xmlns="http://www.geological.com">
    <header>
        <date>08-08-2021</date>
        <jur>US</jur>
    </header>
    <Demographic xmlns="urn:com.test:009">
        <geoData>
            <id>DL89716</id>
            <name>North</name>
        </geoData>
    </Demographic>
</Msg>
```

I am using Java DOM parser to read this xml and fetch value of "id".
Still I am getting value as null

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
document = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlPayLoad)));
document.normalize();

XPathEvaluator xPathObj = (XPathEvaluator)XPathFactory.newInstance(NamespaceConstant.OBJECT_MODEL_SAXON).newXPath();
xPathObj.setNamespaceContext(new MyNameSpace());
xPathObj.getStaticContext().setDefaultElementNamespace("http://www.geological.com");
XPathExpression expr = xPathObj.compile(xpath);
Object result = expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) result;


 private static class MyNameSpace implements NamespaceContext {
       
        //The lookup for the namespace uris is delegated to the stored document.
        public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
            if (prefix.equals(XMLConstants.DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX)) {
                return null;
            } if("ns".equals(prefix)){
                return "urn:com.test:009";
            } 
        }

        public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
            return sourceDocument.lookupPrefix(namespaceURI);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fully functional example:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class NamespacesExample {

  private static String xmlPayLoad =
    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
    "<Msg xmlns=\"http://www.geological.com\">\n" +
    "    <header>\n" +
    "        <date>08-08-2021</date>\n" +
    "        <jur>US</jur>\n" +
    "    </header>\n" +
    "    <Demographic xmlns=\"urn:com.test:009\">\n" +
    "        <geoData>\n" +
    "            <id>DL89716</id>\n" +
    "            <name>North</name>\n" +
    "        </geoData>\n" +
    "    </Demographic>\n" +
    "</Msg>";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder dBuilder = null;
      dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
      dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
      Document document = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlPayLoad)));

      final Map<String, String> ns = new HashMap<>();
      ns.put("geo", "http://www.geological.com");
      ns.put("test", "urn:com.test:009");
      XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
      xpath.setNamespaceContext(new MyNameSpace(ns));

      XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/geo:Msg/test:Demographic/test:geoData/test:id/text()");
      String result = (String) expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);
      System.out.println("Result: " + result);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | IOException | XPathExpressionException | SAXException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }


  private static class MyNameSpace implements NamespaceContext {

    private final Map<String, String> ns;

    MyNameSpace(Map<String, String> ns) {
      this.ns = new HashMap<>(ns);
      this.ns.put(XMLConstants.XML_NS_PREFIX, XMLConstants.XML_NS_URI);
      this.ns.put(XMLConstants.XMLNS_ATTRIBUTE, XMLConstants.XMLNS_ATTRIBUTE_NS_URI);
    }

    @Override
    public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
      if(prefix == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }

      final String uri = ns.get(prefix);
      return uri == null ? XMLConstants.NULL_NS_URI : uri;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
  }
}
```

Some remarks:

The order of these statements is significant. Otherwise there is no namespace awareness:

```
dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
```

Why do you use `XPathEvaluator`? There is no need for that. Using the interface `XPath` is enough.

What is `NamespaceConstant.OBJECT_MODEL_SAXON`? At least in this example, we don't need it.

With my generic `NamespaceContext` implementation you can use a simple `Map<String, String>` to define the namespace prefixes for XPATH evaluation.
Dedicated prefixes should be used for each namespace used in the XML, regardless of how the namespace is declared in the XML document.

Then you can use this XPATH expression to extract the id: `/geo:Msg/test:Demographic/test:geoData/test:id/text()`

Output is:

```
Result: DL89716
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `//*:id` as the path if you know there is a single `id` element you are looking for, or at least there are not several `id` elements from different namespaces and you want to select only those from one namespace.

If you only want to select those from one namespace (e.g. `urn:com.test:009`) then set that as the default namespace and you can simply use `//id` or `//Demographic/geoData/id`.

Only if you really need to select elements from different namespaces you need to bind prefixes.

With the Java 8 built-in JAXP XPathFactory and a not namespace aware DocumentBuilderFactory the following also works for me to select the id element node as then the default namespace declarations are ignored when building the DOM tree:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(false);

    DocumentBuilder jaxpDocumentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document domDoc = jaxpDocumentBuilder.parse(new File("sample1.xml"));

    XPathFactory jaxpXPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

    Node resultDomNode = (Node)jaxpXPathFactory.newXPath().evaluate("/Msg/Demographic/geoData/id", domDoc, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

I think in your original code, once you build a namespace aware DOM, with your use of the Saxon API, you could get away with setting

```
xPathObj.getStaticContext().setUnprefixedElementMatchingPolicy(UnprefixedElementMatchingPolicy.ANY_NAMESPACE);
```

and not to set up any namespace context nor default element namespace.

The other way with Saxon 10 and XPath to match elements in any namespace with selectors like `id` I could find is to dive into its low-level API to mix it with the s9api:

```
    Processor processor = new Processor(false);

    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = processor.newDocumentBuilder();

    XdmNode input = docBuilder.build(new File("sample1.xml"));

    NodeInfo contextItem = input.getUnderlyingNode();

    XPathEvaluator xpathEvaluator = new XPathEvaluator(processor.getUnderlyingConfiguration());

    IndependentContext independentContext = new IndependentContext();
    independentContext.setUnprefixedElementMatchingPolicy(UnprefixedElementMatchingPolicy.ANY_NAMESPACE);

    xpathEvaluator.setStaticContext(independentContext);

    XPathExpression expression = xpathEvaluator.createExpression("/Msg/Demographic/geoData/id");

    NodeInfo resultInfo = (NodeInfo) expression.evaluateSingle(expression.createDynamicContext(contextItem));

    XdmNode resultNode = new XdmNode(resultInfo);

    System.out.println(resultNode);
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. I do need to bind to different namespace.

Comment: @Anurag, fine, but then please show your XPath expressions, otherwise we can't tell whether the namespace bindings in the Java code make any sense.

Comment: I would be getting dump of xpaths in an excel (around 500+) starting with my root node.  So it will be impossible to change my xpath's or edit it

/Msg/Demographic/geoData/id
/Msg/Demographic/geoData/name
/Msg/Demographic/.. something else

Comment: @Anurag, if you expect a path like `/Msg/Demographic/geoData/id` to work against that input document with elements being in two different namespaces you won't find a way for that in any XPath implementation working on a namespace aware DOM and implementing standard XPath. Your only bet would be a not namespace aware DOM, but I am not event sure Saxon supports that. For XSLT, the latest Saxon version has https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/UnprefixedElementMatchingPolicy.html#ANY_NAMESPACE but I am not sure you can set that for XPath.